# Prevent url changes on navigation Vue.js/Nuxt.js

Tags: url, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have vue.js/nuxt app.

Currently my routes, during navigation are something like this:

http://localhost:3001/Persona/frmListadoRaza
http://localhost:3001/estudiante/frmEstudiante

As the deaulf behavior it is.

But as a requiment, I need to somehow, mask (sort of) or hide the routes generated during navigation.

so even tho I navigate to, http://localhost:3001/Persona/frmListadoRaza, the url keep static like http://localhost:3001/.

Does any of you good people, have an advise, recomendation or documentation on how to archive this? Any coment is well received.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt autogenerates routes from your `pages` directory.

You are probably defining `Persona/frmListadoRaza` and `estudiante/frmEstudiante` in your `pages`, so the route appears that way.

Instead define them in `components`, then import and use them in your `pages/index.vue` which corresponds to the base url(`/`).

Start with the default view at `/` and then hide and/or show the components as you need.

Comment: I get it, but, would you recomend this architecture for large projects?

Comment: Switching out large number of components might be a bad idea, but if your hierarchy is such that there are fewer components in your index.vue, each of which have sub-components, it should be fine. Also have look at https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2018/07/16/7-tips-large-nuxt-app-vue/ for defining custom routes